# IME "Enter" key behave like "Send" in FB Messenger

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, ime

While using **FB Messenger**,

In my Custom Keyboard, pressing "Enter" key -> send the message.

But in Google keyboard,  pressing "Enter" key -> goes to new line.

***How do I go to new line pressing "Enter" key of my custom keyboard?***

```
                EditorInfo editorInfo = getCurrentInputEditorInfo();
                int imeOptions = editorInfo != null ? editorInfo.imeOptions : -77;
                switch (imeOptions & (EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION|EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)) {
                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO:
                        ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
                        break;
                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                        ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
                        break;
                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
                        ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
                        break;
                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND:
                        ic.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND);
                        break;
                    default:
                        // seems like passing here but sending the message
                        ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
                        break;
                }
```

Comment: Hello. Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is listen to when a key is pressed like this:

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
        // Get the text in the TextView or whatever and append the "\n" to it.
        textView.setText(textView.getText.toString() + "\n");
    }
}
```

This listens to when a key is pressed and then checks if the key that was pressed was the `Enter` key. Then, it adds a new line by doing `\n`. I hope this helps.